# How to use data in a nested object in a laravel Blade view?

Tags: php, object, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use data in a nested object in a laravel Blade view.

I am using Laravel 4.2.

Here is a sample of the data, "$arContent":

```
stdClass Object
(
    [h1-title] => stdClass Object
        (
            [h3-sub-title] => Safe, Affordable Self-Storage
            [img] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Caption 1
                    [1] => Caption 2
                    [2] => Caption 4
                )
        )
)
```

I pass it to the view, "objects":

```
// show the view and pass the page and domain recrods to it
return View::make('objects')
    ->with('page', $page)
    ->with('content', $arContent)
    ->with('domain', $domain);
```

And here I am trying to retrieve a value in the view:

```
<h2>
{{ $content->h1-title->h3-sub-title }}
</h2>
```

The error that I get from above is:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$h1

I have also tried:

```
<h2>
    {{ $content->h1-title->h3-sub-title }}
</h2>
```

And I then get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or
>   ';'

I think it's obvious what I am trying to do:  I want to be able to access the values of the nested object as many "layers" down as I want.  I have searched Google for the different approaches tried above and right now I don't know if Laravel is expecting something different / does not support this or if I am doing something stupid.

Any guidance on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `var_dump($content)` in the view - it's not the sollution but maybe will help

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
{{ $content->{'h1-title'}->{'h3-sub-title'} }}
```

You get error, because you can't call propert with "-". Try to avoid names with "-".
Much more better name will be "h1_title" "h3_sub_title"

Comment: Wow.  Awesome.  Where in the world is that in the Blade docs?

Comment: @shamelesshacker - This has nothing to do with blade. It's straight up PHP.